# How do I authenticate a WebClient request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

I am making a call to a page on my site using webclient. I'm trying to get the result of the webpage put into a pdf so I am trying to get a string representation of the rendered page. The problem is that the request is not authenticated so all I get is a login screen. I have sent the UseDefaultCredentials property to true but I still get the same result. Below is a portion of my code:

```
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
 webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

 webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
 return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(webClient.UploadValues(link, "POST",form));
```

Comment: Found very nice solution [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624624/Using-a-Cookie-Aware-WebClient-to-Persist-Authenti)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of authentication are you using? If it's Forms authentication, then at best, you'll have to find the .ASPXAUTH cookie and pass it in the `WebClient` request.

At worst, it won't work.

Comment: Then you need `WebClient` to behave like a browser woould have behaved. You need to send the cookie.

Comment: Um, not sure how I would do that. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Get the cookie using Request.Cookies, then send it by using HttpWebRequest.Cookies. You won;t be able to use WebClient.

Comment: @black I agree.

Answer (score 119):

You need to give the WebClient object the credentials.  Something like this...

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Comment: This worked.  Note that I didn't have to set UseDefaultCredentials to true.

Comment: Where you passed website address

Comment: the package is having difficulties with the WebClient  , I cannot right click to resolve as there is no option to do this ...please help

Comment: What if the credentials are correct but this results in a `401 Unauthorized`?

Comment: which dependency should i use to work with NetworkCredential?

Answer (score 0):

This helped me to call API that was using cookie authentication. I have passed authorization in header like this:

```
request.Headers.Set("Authorization", Utility.Helper.ReadCookie("AuthCookie"));
```

complete code:

```
// utility method to read the cookie value:
        public static string ReadCookie(string cookieName)
        {
            var cookies = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies;
            var cookie = cookies.Get(cookieName);
            if (cookie != null)
                return cookie.Value;
            return null;
        }

// using statements where you are creating your webclient
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

// WebClient:

var requestUrl = "<API_url>";
var postRequest = new ClassRoom { name = "kushal seth" };

using (var webClient = new WebClient()) {
      JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
      byte[] requestData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serializer.Serialize(postRequest));
      HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
      request.Method = "POST";
      request.ContentType = "application/json";                        
      request.ContentLength = requestData.Length;
      request.ContentType = "application/json";
      request.Expect = "application/json";
      request.Headers.Set("Authorization", Utility.Helper.ReadCookie("AuthCookie"));
      request.GetRequestStream().Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);

      using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {
         var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
         var objText = reader.ReadToEnd(); // objText will have the value
      }
}
```

Comment: It's a working code. AuthCookie will be your cookie