# Error when download XML file by using webclient

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm using this code to get XML data from URl:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "admin");
    string xml = wc.DownloadString("http://somedomain.com:8550/epe/postaglist");

    XmlDocument tournamentsXML = new XmlDocument();
    tournamentsXML.LoadXml(xml);


    XmlNodeList TagList = tournamentsXML.GetElementsByTagName("TAG");
    foreach (XmlNode node in TagList)
    {
        XmlElement TagElement = (XmlElement)node;
        string TagID = TagElement.GetElementsByTagName("tagid")[0].InnerText;
        string MAC = TagElement.GetElementsByTagName("mac")[0].InnerText;
        Messagbox.Show(TagID+","+MAC));
    }
}
```

And it work fine 100%. But when change the link to add query string like this:

"http://somedomain.com:8550/epe/pos/taglist?fields=posgood"

It give me authentication exception 401 Please note that it work fine on IE or firefox browsers !!

I'm tired because still trying from yesterday to solve this exception and I can't :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is just an error in your question, or if it's in your code. In the code sample, you are trying to get this URL:

```
http://somedomain.com:8550/epe/postaglist
```

but in your discussion below, you have:

```
http://somedomain.com:8550/epe/pos/taglist
```

In any case, if you get a 401 error, it means that you have to supply some kind of credentials. Perhaps the site requires a user name and password. You need to look into setting the [Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials.aspx) property of your `WebClient`.

See also [How do I authenticate a WebClient request?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1883655/56778), and the various answers.

Comment: This is mistake only, and I'm trying what mention in the link and still Authentication error 401 :(