# Getting WebClient to remember IE cache?

Tags: c#, .net

I couldn't find anything via google so I thought I would ask here. Is there a way to make C#'s WebClient library use IE cache, I am trying to download a string but the page is only available to logged in users.

Comment: Think about 'what if this were possible?' If it were, then my app running on your machine could use `WebClient` without you being aware. It could load your `gmail.com` and read your emails and send your cookies to another machine so that your emails could be read from elsewhere. This is somewhat dangerous. :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I authenticate a WebClient request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883655/how-do-i-authenticate-a-webclient-request)

Comment: `WebClient` is an independent implementation of the HTTP protocol and does not rely on any browser, including IE. Figure out how the authentication works in IE, then make `WebClient` do the same. Alternatively, automate IE.