# How can I download files and save them in a folder from a website protected with user and password?

Tags: powershell

I want to make a script to download files from a website protected with a username and password, but since the website asks for username and password first, I am stuck and do not know what do to make the script.

```
$iIp = Read-Host -Prompt 'eneter your ip'

foreach($line in Get-Content .\urls.txt) {
    if($line -match $regex){

    $url = "$Ip/$line"

    if (!(Test-Path .\descargados)){
        mkdir .\downloads | Out-Null
    }
    $path = ".\downloads\$line"


    if(!(Split-Path -parent $path) -or !(Test-Path -pathType Container (Split-Path -parent $path))) {
      $path = Join-Path $pwd (Split-Path -leaf $path)
    }


    "downloading and saving [$line]"
    $client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
    $client.DownloadFile($url, $path)


    $path
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks like Powershell to me, so I am not sure why you used the bash, shell and batch-file tags.

Comment: yes, i am open to everything, i just posted that as an example but i can use other things.
if the the example of powershell i post it, is  leading to confusion you can delete it because i cant edit my question because i am new here

Comment: Nope.  That is not how you ask questions on StackOverFlow.  Your questions must be specific to the programming language you are using.

Comment: thank you for editing it

Comment: I think [answer for using WebClient authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1883697/3344991) will help. It's in C#, but the class is the same in both languages.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6) as it has the ability for you to use credentials or fill out forms via POST. The [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6#examples) there show several use cases. You may need to use -AllowUnencryptedAuthentication as you don't seem to have any ssl in place.

```
$credential = Get-Credential

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url `
              -AllowUnencryptedAuthentication `
              -Credential $credential `
              -OutFile $path
```