# windows authentication in windows service

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory, installutil

Windows service throwing error ACCESS DENIED While trying to access website that uses windows authentication.
While deploying this service its using NT-Authority as windows credential

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string page = wc.DownloadString("https://abcxyz.com/");
```

Comment: I think this is an _[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)_, try to specify what are you trying to do rather that just exploring the issue with your current approach

Comment: Unable to get user/pwd from active directory .

Comment: "Help me install my malware as services without asking for permissions" type of questions rarely fare well on SO. Some starting points so you can [edit] post to demonstrate your research  - AD does not store passwords... Unconstrained elevation of privileges (especially to admin/system level accounts) is not something you can do in any system...

Comment: You have to grant the identity of this Windows service the permissions to access external services (and maybe also configure a valid proxy for it if by default it cannot connect externally). Typical system session (session 0) issue so you can find tons of similar posts.

Comment: Although when  i use  wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true; its working on local debugging session

Comment: You just need to set the [`Credentials`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.credentials?view=netframework-4.8) property with the credentials you want to use. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1883697/1202807).

Comment: When i am debugging service its taking my user credentials but on deploying service it is getting username as NT_Authority